# Pandas increment every nth row in dataframe with conditions and groupby

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

This is a simplified example of my current dataframe (df1), after merging results from a nested loop calculation back to customer data.
My actual dataframe is 10 million rows+, so im dealing with large data, and would prefer the fastest way.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"id": ['z111','z111','z111','z111','z112','z112','z112','z112'], #customer data
                    "calc_amt": [1000,500,200,300,100,50,30,200],
                    "month_end":['28-02-2023','28-02-2023','28-02-2023','28-02-2023','28-02-2023','28-02-2023','28-02-2023','28-02-2023'],
                    "period":[2,2,2,2,6,6,6,6],})
```

I am trying to find the most efficient way to do the following;
grouping by each users id, id like to,

increment every 3rd row in the column name period by 1
increment every 3rd row in the column name month_end by 1 (to the next month_end date)
add a calculation number column to label the calculations(calc_num).

My expected output (df2)

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"id": ['z111','z111','z111','z111','z112','z112','z112','z112'], #customer data
                    "calc_amt": [1000,500,200,300,100,50,30,200],
                    "month_end":['28-02-2023','28-02-2023','31-03-2023','31-03-2023','28-02-2023','28-02-2023','31-03-2023','31-03-2023'],
                    "period":[2,2,3,3,6,6,7,7],
                    "calc_num":[1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2],})
```

Comment: It's every **2nd** row in your example, not **3rd**, of if this is really a period of 3, do you skip the first? Maybe add a few more rows for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`groupby.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) to enumerate the rows per group, then use the modulo or floor division:

```
N = 2 # periodicity

# ensure datetime
df1['month_end'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['month_end'])

# enumerate rows
c = df1.groupby('id').cumcount()

df1['period'] += c.floordiv(N)
df1['calc_num'] = c.mod(N).add(1)
df1['month_end'] += np.array([pd.offsets.MonthEnd(x) for x in c.floordiv(2)])
```

*NB. if you want to create a new dataframe, first run `df2 = df1.copy()`, then use `df2`.*

Output:

```
     id  calc_amt  month_end  period  calc_num
0  z111      1000 2023-02-28       2         1
1  z111       500 2023-02-28       2         2
2  z111       200 2023-03-31       3         1
3  z111       300 2023-03-31       3         2
4  z111       400 2023-04-30       4         1
5  z111       450 2023-04-30       4         2
6  z112       100 2023-02-28       6         1
7  z112        50 2023-02-28       6         2
8  z112        30 2023-03-31       7         1
9  z112       200 2023-03-31       7         2
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for counter with integer and modulo division by `2`, last add next months with converting to month periods by [`Serie.dt.to_period`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.to_period.html):

```
df1['month_end'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['month_end'])

g = df1.groupby('id').cumcount()

df2 = df1.assign(period = df1['period'] + g // 2,
                 calc_num = g % 2 + 1,
                 month_end = (df1['month_end'].dt.to_period('m') + 
                              g // 2).dt.to_timestamp(how='e').dt.normalize())

print (df2)
     id  calc_amt  month_end  period  calc_num
0  z111      1000 2023-02-28       2         1
1  z111       500 2023-02-28       2         2
2  z111       200 2023-03-31       3         1
3  z111       300 2023-03-31       3         2
4  z112       100 2023-02-28       6         1
5  z112        50 2023-02-28       6         2
6  z112        30 2023-03-31       7         1
7  z112       200 2023-03-31       7         2
```

Or use lsit comprehension with [`offsets.MonthEnd`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.MonthEnd.html):

```
df1['month_end'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['month_end'])

g = df1.groupby('id').cumcount()

df2 = df1.assign(period = df1['period'] + g // 2,
                 calc_num = g % 2 + 1,
                 month_end = [x + pd.offsets.MonthEnd(y) for x , y 
                              in zip(df1['month_end'], g // 2)])

print (df2)
     id  calc_amt  month_end  period  calc_num
0  z111      1000 2023-02-28       2         1
1  z111       500 2023-02-28       2         2
2  z111       200 2023-03-31       3         1
3  z111       300 2023-03-31       3         2
4  z112       100 2023-02-28       6         1
5  z112        50 2023-02-28       6         2
6  z112        30 2023-03-31       7         1
7  z112       200 2023-03-31       7         2
```

Because working with large DataFrame, here is trick for add monhts effectively - trick is add next months from integer division by `2` and subtract one day:

```
df1['month_end'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['month_end'])

g = df1.groupby('id').cumcount()

df2 = df1.assign(period = df1['period'] + g // 2,
                 calc_num = g % 2 + 1,
                 month_end = df1['month_end'].values.astype('datetime64[M]') + 
                             np.array(g.to_numpy() // 2 + 1, dtype='timedelta64[M]') - 
                             np.array([1], dtype='timedelta64[D]')
                             )

print (df2)
     id  calc_amt  month_end  period  calc_num
0  z111      1000 2023-02-28       2         1
1  z111       500 2023-02-28       2         2
2  z111       200 2023-03-31       3         1
3  z111       300 2023-03-31       3         2
4  z112       100 2023-02-28       6         1
5  z112        50 2023-02-28       6         2
6  z112        30 2023-03-31       7         1
7  z112       200 2023-03-31       7         2
```